# Reading in strings in C

Tags: c, string

I'm looking for the most efficient way to read in a collection of words given to me in a text file.

The program I am writing is basically Scrabble.  It will generate 7 random letters (already done) and then the user will need to input a word out of any number of those letters (like in Scrabble), and the program will score the word (also already done).

The issue I am facing now is how to read in the words.  We are given a file with 80 words that is like the generic "dictionary" for this project. I was thinking of using either the `fopen()` function or manually typing in the words (which would suck...). I am facing another problem of how to store the words. I was thinking of a 2d array where each column or row was a word.  There is a limit of 10,000 words and they can be no more than 6 letters long.

Any tips on how to do this would be great.

Comment: I would just load the txt file into a string and then check if this string contains the word that was formed out of the letters. Words in the file should be seperated by a whitespace or a comma of course

Comment: How are the words listed in the file? It seems you should be doing a google search before posting here...

Comment: Should this be tagged as homework?

Comment: @Marvo: See [Can we discourage the use of and burninate the homework tag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123758/can-we-now-discourage-the-use-of-and-burninate-the-homework-tag) on MSO.  It doesn't have official status, but it is fairly well up-voted and fairly recent (2012-02-28).  I've answered this question on the assumption that it is homework and that a complete coded solution is not appropriate.

Comment: The 'canonical' MSO reference on homework is [How to ask and answer homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score 3):

Read the words into a dynamically allocated array of strings.

1. Open the file (`fopen()`).
2. Read each line of the file (`fgets()`).  Make everything mono-case (all upper-case, or all lower-case; `<ctype.h>`).
3. (If necessary) Split the line into words (`<string.h>`; `strspn()` or `strcspn()` perhaps).
4. For each word, allocate enough memory and copy it into that memory (`strdup()` if available; otherwise write your own).
5. Store the pointer to the string in a dynamically allocated array of pointers (`malloc()`, `realloc()`).
6. Close the file at the end (`fclose()`).
7. Sort the array of strings for rapid look-up (`qsort()`).
8. Use binary search to look for words (`bsearch()`).

---

If you've not been taught about pointers, let alone arrays of pointers, then you can still use steps 1-3 and 6-8 verbatim.  You'd preallocate a 2D array of characters, 10,000 x 7 (since the max word length is 6), and keep a record of how many are in use (a simple counter).  Make sure none of the strings is longer than 6 characters; make sure there are no more than 10,000 words in total.

The comparison function you need for `qsort()` and `bsearch()` are a little different in this case.

You could forego the efficiency of binary search and use a simple linear search.

Comment: The requirements contain hard limits. Those are probably included in order avoid requiring the use of `malloc`.

Comment: That's a possibility; doubly so if pointers have not yet been taught.  I'm not sure whether the questioner would be aware of not having been taught pointers.